# DbContext returns irrelevant data from the Oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

The DbContext returns irrelevant data from the Oracle database.
Getting the database context is implemented through IServiceScopeFactory, because the method that adds the DbContext to the DI container is Scoped, and my part uses IHostedService, which requires creating an area (Scope).

```
protected SomeCtor(...)
{
   IServiceScope scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope();
   DbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TContext>();
}
```

I then retrieve the data in this way:

```
protected override IAsyncEnumerable<TItem> GetItemsFromDBAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return DbContext.Set<TItem>().Where(...).AsAsyncEnumerable();
}
```

My DbContext is set in a standard way by inheriting from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext

```
public class SomeDbContext : DbContext
{
  (...)
   public SomeDbContext (DbContextOptions<SomeDbContext > options)
            : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.HasDefaultSchema("SchemaName");

            builder.Entity<SomeItem1>(x => x
               .ToTable("SomeTable1")
            );

            builder.Entity<SomeItem2>(x => x
               .ToTable("SomeTable2")
            );

            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
}
```

And often ( not every time) I get data from a table that is no longer in the database. It feels like the context is not updated. Correct data starts loading after several program restarts.

No one else works with this table.

Comment: Does `scope` is disposed? Why do you need `Scope`? When `DbContext` is registerd as scoped, ASP.NET creates scope for each request automatically. How result of `GetItemsFromDBAsync` is used later?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv this is used in hosted service, so no automatic scope creation there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `DbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<TContext>();`

I would recommend against doing that in the service. It seems that you resolve the `SomeCtor` in your `IHostedService` which makes lifetime of the `DbContext` match the lifetime of the hosted service itself. `DbContext` is designed to be lightweight so I highly recommend to switch to "per iteration" approach, i.e. let the `IHostedService` create short-lived scopes and resolve needed stuff inside the scope:

```cs
class MyHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public MyHostedService(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // todo manage stoppage 

        while (true)
        {
            await using var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateAsyncScope();
            // SomeService - usual scoped service using DbContext, etc. ...
            var service scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<SomeService>();
            await service.ProcessIterationAsync();
        }
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

The problem you are facing is highly likely related to the fact that you are not disposing/recreating/clearing context. EF Core is using [tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/) to manage changes and if there is some stale information in change tracker it can lead to reading stale data from it without hitting database (or even hitting it but still using some parts of stale data, also I have performance issues related to change tracker in such scenarios at least in earlier versions of EF Core). At least call `Clear` on the change tracker - `DbContext.ChangeTracker.Clear();`

Also check out [consuming a scoped service in a background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task) parts of the docs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Do I understand correctly that ChangeTracker.Clear() is an alternative to the method above. And the way above is a better implementation of my approach?

Comment: @A.Max yes it kind of is, but I would recommend to still follow the short-lived scopes approach. Since you have not posted full code it is hard to say how exactly it relates to yours.

Comment: I click accepted your answer, but could you answer me one last question: 
if I temporarily choose ChangeTracker.Clear() before switching to your method, at what point is it best to do Clear?

Comment: @A.Max and the end of every "iteration". usually hosted service either run infinite loop or process some queue or invoked by timer, so consider an iteration to be iteration for loops, every item for queue and single timer callback for timers. I.e. the same time you would dispose the scope in the suggested implementation. Also check out the linked docs.