# How to get the updated record after ExecuteUpdate()?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm doing an integration test (real object, no mocks) for a method that executes the below code:

```
await _domainContext.User
             .Where(x => x.Id == userId)
             .ExecuteUpdateAsync(s =>
                 s.SetProperty(p => p.NumberOfFollowing, p => p.NumberOfFollowing + 1));
```

I can see on the DB that the value has been increased correctly (before was 0. After the update, it's 1)

After that, I want to assert  `p.NumberOfFollowing` if it has been increased, so I do the below:

```
 int updatedValue =  _domainContext.User.Single(x => x.Id == userId).NumberOfFollowing;
```

But the value is always zero (not getting the updated one).

In the test I create the DB context in the Setup and it is shared with all repsitories

Comment: What is `_userRepository`? What is `All`? If it is wrapper around EF then it seems to be an example of using stale data from the change tracker (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72924796/how-does-caching-work-in-entity-framework-core-6-06/72925114#72925114) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75788722/2501279)). Try either call `DbContext.ChangeTracker.Clear` or recreating the `_userRepository` with newly scoped context.

Comment: @GuruStron public virtual IQueryable<T> All()
        {
            return this.Set;
        }

Comment: ExecuteUpdate bypasses the change tracked  so you must issue a query

Comment: `public virtual IQueryable<T> All() { return this.Set; }` - there is an argument that since EF Core already implements repository and UoW than wrapping it up into a repository is an antipattern, while I don't completely agree with it, in my personal opinion wrapping it into repository which exposes  `IQueryable` is kind definitely one.

Comment: @ErikEJ OP issues a query - `int updatedValue = _userRepository.All().Single(x => x.Id == userId).NumberOfFollowing;` which (I think) returns stale data. My theory is that somewhere along the pipeline the data was fetched and is present in change tracker, hence the behaviour (EF will skip mapping data in case of it being present in change tracker AFAIK).

Comment: @GuruStron I have changed it using domain context directly. same issue.

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso what is "domain context"? Can you please provide a [mre]? Again, see my previous comments. Just changing to use context directly will not solve the issue. Clear change tracker before the query, recreate the context or use `var user = _domainContext.User.Single(x => x.Id == userId); _domainContext.Entry(user).Reload();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are using the same instance of the context in both cases. And it seems that you have fetched the user somewhere during the request handling with enabled change tracking, which leads to the stale data. `ExecuteUpdateAsync` will bypass the change tracking mechanism, so you can try one of the following:

1. Recreate the context: `int updatedValue = GetNewContextSomeHow().User.Single(x => x.Id == userId).NumberOfFollowing;`
2. Clear change tracker:

```cs
_domainContext.ChangeTracker.Clear();
int updatedValue = _domainContext.User.Single(x => x.Id == userId).NumberOfFollowing;
```

3. Explicitly reloading the data:

```cs
var user = _domainContext.User.Single(x => x.Id == userId);
_domainContext.Entry(user).Reload();
int updatedValue = user.NumberOfFollowing;
```

Also maybe just `int updatedValue = _domainContext.User.AsNoTracking().Single(x => x.Id == userId).NumberOfFollowing;` will work but I can't test it at the moment.